# Shiny app progress bar for whole set of reactive functions

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I am working on a Shiny app where the user can pick a gene from a drop-down menu, hit a submit button, and then gets displayed a set of different graphs for that gene. The computation to generate all those graphs takes some time and I would like Shiny to display a progress bar or some notification that it is busy, so that the user stays away from the submit button.

I found withProgress() and the Progress object in Shiny, yet - if I got that right - those always have to be placed inside of one reactive function and then display the progress of that very function. However, I have a whole set of different renderPlot() functions to be processed, and would like to display the cummulative progress of all of them.

When searching the web I also found the package ShinySky, which seems to feature a busyIndicator that can be set to turn on when Shiny is busy longer than a certain time. However, I have been given the error message "package ‘shinysky’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)" when I tried to install it.

I generated a small dummy app using the nycflights13 weather data with a time delay to illustrate the refreshing of the plots after changing the input:

```
library(shiny)
library(nycflights13)

ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, offset = 0,
        titlePanel("Look up airport weather data"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(3, offset = 0,
        selectizeInput(inputId = "airportName", label = "",
          choices = c("EWR", "JFK", "LGA")))),
    fluidRow(
      column(12, offset = 0,
        actionButton(inputId = "klickButton", label = "Submit")))),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, offset = 0,
      plotOutput(outputId = "windHist")),
    column(6, offset = 0,
      plotOutput(outputId = "windData"))),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, offset = 0,
      plotOutput(outputId = "precipData")),
    column(6, offset = 0,
      plotOutput(outputId = "tempData")))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  wSubset <- eventReactive(input$klickButton, {
    subset(weather, weather$origin == input$airportName)})
  output$windHist <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(1)
    hist(wSubset()$wind_dir)})
  output$windData <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(1)
    plot(wSubset()$wind_speed, wSubset()$wind_gust)})
  output$precipData <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(1)
    plot(wSubset()$humid, wSubset()$precip)})
  output$tempData <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(1)
    plot(wSubset()$temp, wSubset()$dewp)})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am looking for a way to display a progress bar that starts when the first function gets busy after hitting the submit button and continues until all of the plots are made. If that gets too complicated I am also happy with any other means of telling the user that someting is actually happening in the background and thus asking for some patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to solve this but with a spinner on each plot. It is completely based on [this](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/plot-spinner/app.R) solution by Dean Atali. The JS code is needed to hide the spinner before the Submit button is clicked. Once the button is clicked the spinner will be showed. Put the [spinner.gif](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/plot-spinner/www/spinner.gif) and the JS code in the www folder.

spinnerManage.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#klickButton').click(function() {
            $(".loading-spinner").show();
        });  
    });
    $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
            $(".loading-spinner").hide();
    });
```

app.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(nycflights13)

    mycss <- "
    .plot-container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .loading-spinner {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: -1;
      margin-top: -33px;  /* half of the spinner's height */
      margin-left: -33px; /* half of the spinner's width */
    }
    "

    ui <- fluidPage(
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(mycss)),
                      includeScript("./www/spinnerManage.js")),
            wellPanel(
                    fluidRow(
                            column(12, offset = 0,
                                   titlePanel("Look up airport weather data"))),
                    fluidRow(
                            column(3, offset = 0,
                                   selectizeInput(inputId = "airportName", label = "",
                                                  choices = c("EWR", "JFK", "LGA")))),
                    fluidRow(
                            column(12, offset = 0,
                                   actionButton(inputId = "klickButton", label = "Submit")))),
            fluidRow(
                    column(6, offset = 0,
                           div(class = "plot-container",
                                       tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
                                                class = "loading-spinner"),           
                           plotOutput(outputId = "windHist"))
                    ),
                    column(6, offset = 0,
                           div(class = "plot-container",
                               tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
                                        class = "loading-spinner"),           
                               plotOutput(outputId = "windData"))
                           )),
            fluidRow(
                    column(6, offset = 0,
                           div(class = "plot-container",
                               tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
                                        class = "loading-spinner"),           
                               plotOutput(outputId = "precipData"))
                           ),
                    column(6, offset = 0,
                           div(class = "plot-container",
                               tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
                                        class = "loading-spinner"),           
                               plotOutput(outputId = "tempData"))
    ))
    )


    server <- function(input, output) {
            wSubset <- eventReactive(input$klickButton, {
                    subset(weather, weather$origin == input$airportName)})
            output$windHist <- renderPlot({
                    Sys.sleep(1)
                    hist(wSubset()$wind_dir)})
            output$windData <- renderPlot({
                    Sys.sleep(1)
                    plot(wSubset()$wind_speed, wSubset()$wind_gust)})
            output$precipData <- renderPlot({
                    Sys.sleep(1)
                    plot(wSubset()$humid, wSubset()$precip)})
            output$tempData <- renderPlot({
                    Sys.sleep(1)
                    plot(wSubset()$temp, wSubset()$dewp)})
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there also a way to display a spinner for example right next to the submit button? It might be a bit tricky, since it looks like that the spinners are always there after the Submit button is hit for the first time, and then just get covered by the plots, right? Is there a way to have them dynamically appear and disappear?

Comment: I guess there is a solution, I could take a look at it this weekend. Sunday most probably...